# Landau Lifshitz pseudotensor -- energy density

Tags: general-relativity, conservation-laws, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Landau-Lifshitz stress-energy pseudotensor $t^{ik}$ is defined in such a way that, combined with matter stress-energy tensor $T^{ik}$, it leads to continuity equation:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k} \left[(-g)\left(t^{ik} + T^{ik}\right)\right] = 0
$$
which, under appropriate boundary condition, can be transformed into conservation law for
$$
P^i = \int d^3x (-g)\left(t^{i0} + T^{i0}\right)
$$
where $d^3x = dx^1dx^2dx^3$.

However, energy/momentum density of matter is given by $T^{i0}$, and infinitesimal element of physical volume is $\sqrt{-g}d^3x$, so, it seems to me, that the expression above for $P^i$ has an extra $\sqrt{-g}$, doesn't it? It should be
$$
P^i = \int d^3x \sqrt{-g}\left(\textrm{something}^{i0} + T^{i0}\right)
$$

So while $t^{ik}$ provides a conservation law, it's not actually conservation of matter+grav.field momentum?

Answer (score 1):

The conserved quantity is
$$
\left[(-g)\left(t^{ik} + T^{ik}\right)\right]
$$
and not
$$
\left(t^{ik} + T^{ik}\right)
$$
irrespective of the way you write the volume element (with or without $\sqrt{-g}$).

About the multiplier $\sqrt{-g}$, we have to account that $t^{ik}$ is not a tensor but a pseudotensor composed of metric first derivatives. One variant of $t^{ik}$ uses $\Gamma$ connections. The latter are tensors in respect to linear transformations but are not tensors in respect to rotations (the proof is about half a page). As Landau-Lifshitz chapter 96 explain, the gravitationally interacting system cuts a "channel" in spacetime, outside of which all fields (including the gravitational one) are zero. Inside the channel, the four-momentum $P^i$ (the integral) is conserved, and its value does not depend on the particular coordinate system used. In particular, we can use Cartesian system, for which $\sqrt{-g} = 1$. The exact citation in the footnote:

"[footnote] Strictly speaking, in the definition (96.11) $P^i$ is a four-vector only with respect to linear transformations  with determinant equal to unity; among these are the Lorentz transformations, which alone are of physical interest. If we also admit transformations with determinant not equal to unity, then we must introduce into the definition of $P^i$ the value of $g$ at infinity by writing $\sqrt{-g_{\infty}} P^i$ in place of $P^i$ on the left side of (96.11)."

Comment: That's right, what I mean is that it's not simply a sum of matter stress-energy tensor and field stress-energy tensor, like, say, in case of EM field. An additional multiplier of $\sqrt{-g}$ affects $T^{ik}$ as well.

Comment: Now, this is a bit longer explanation, so I will put it in the main text.